# Welding IIWA arm to a Planar Joint

Tags: python, robotics, drake

Me and my friends are trying to obtain a mobile IIWA arm using PyDrake library. We are able to manually define a planar joint using two Prismatic joints and one Revolute joint. First, we were playing with a basic box to move around. However, when adding the IIWA arm, our program started to give the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "planar_joint.py", line 107, in <module>
    simulator.AdvanceTo(12.0)
RuntimeError: Error control wants to select step smaller than minimum allowed (1e-14)
```

I read that might be caused by singularity of IIWA but I believe we did not force IIWA to obtain a such position. Another thing I have read was the cause of this problem might be getting an infinite value in the physics engine. It is more likely but I do not know how to fix the problem. You can find the code below.

Main Code:

```
meshcat = StartMeshcat()

meshcat.Flush()
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0005)

parser = Parser(plant)

scene_models = parser.AddModels("cargobot-models/scene_without_robot.dmd.yaml")

iiwa = plant.GetModelInstanceByName("iiwa")

false_body = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "false_body", iiwa,
        SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)))
false_body2 = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "false_body2", iiwa,
        SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)))

mobile_base_y = plant.AddJoint(PrismaticJoint(
        "mobile_base_y", plant.GetFrameByName("world"), plant.GetFrameByName("false_body"), 
        [0, 1, 0], -3, 3))
plant.AddJointActuator("mobile_base_y_actuator", mobile_base_y)

mobile_base_x = plant.AddJoint(PrismaticJoint(
        "mobile_base_x", plant.GetFrameByName("false_body"), plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"), 
        [1, 0, 0], -3, 3))
plant.AddJointActuator("mobile_base_x_actuator", mobile_base_x)

mobile_base_theta = plant.AddJoint(RevoluteJoint(
        "mobile_base_theta", plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"), plant.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_0"), 
        [0, 0, 1],  -np.pi, np.pi))
plant.AddJointActuator("mobile_base_theta_actuator", mobile_base_theta)

plant.Finalize()

visualizer = MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(
    builder, scene_graph, meshcat)

plant_context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()

kp=[100] * plant.num_positions()
ki=[1] * plant.num_positions()
kd=[20] * plant.num_positions()

planar_controller = builder.AddSystem(
    InverseDynamicsController(plant, kp, ki, kd, False))
planar_controller.set_name("planar_controller")
builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(),
                planar_controller.get_input_port_estimated_state())
builder.Connect(planar_controller.get_output_port_control(),
                plant.get_actuation_input_port())

diagram = builder.Build()
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()

states = [1, 0, 0, -1.57, 0.1, 0, -1.2, 0, 1.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
planar_controller.GetInputPort('desired_state').FixValue(
    planar_controller.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context), states)

simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
visualizer.StartRecording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(12.0)
visualizer.StopRecording()
visualizer.PublishRecording()
```

Yaml file for the scene:

```
directives:          
    - add_model:
        name: cargo-space
        file: file:///usr/cargobot/cargobot-project/trajopt/cargobot-models/cargo-space.sdf

    - add_weld:
        parent: world
        child: cargo-space::cargo-space
        X_PC:
            rotation: !Rpy { deg: [0, 90, 0 ]}
            translation: [-1.5, 0, 0.4]

    - add_frame: 
        name: table_top_center
        X_PF:
            base_frame: world
            rotation: !Rpy { deg: [0, 0, 0]}
            translation: [0, 0, -0.5]

    - add_model:
        name: table_top
        file: file:///usr/cargobot/cargobot-project/trajopt/cargobot-models/table_top.sdf

    - add_weld: 
        parent: table_top_center
        child: table_top_link

    - add_model:
        name: iiwa
        file: package://drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/iiwa7/iiwa7_no_collision.sdf
        default_joint_positions:
            iiwa_joint_1: [-1.57]
            iiwa_joint_2: [0.1]
            iiwa_joint_3: [0]
            iiwa_joint_4: [-1.2]
            iiwa_joint_5: [0]
            iiwa_joint_6: [ 1.6]
            iiwa_joint_7: [0]

    - add_model:
        name: wsg
        file: package://drake/manipulation/models/wsg_50_description/sdf/schunk_wsg_50_with_tip.sdf
    - add_weld:
        parent: iiwa::iiwa_link_7
        child: wsg::body
        X_PC:
            translation: [0, 0, 0.09]
            rotation: !Rpy { deg: [90, 0, 90]}
```

We tried to set the robot 1 unit to the left.

Comment: You probably didn't realize that pydrake already has a [PlanarJoint](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.tree.html?highlight=planarjoint#pydrake.multibody.tree.PlanarJoint). Presumably, this doesn't  solve your problem, but it might be convenient.

Comment: Thank you for the response! We tried adding PlanarJoint. However, our system needs actuators to make the system mobile. I believe, it is not easy, or possible, to add actuators to joints which have dof>1. Hence, we wanted to add 3 joints to imitate the planar joint, as Russ Tedrake implements and mentions as well in one of the posts in Stackoverflow. Is there any development on this issue to make PlanarJoint usage easier? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Adding 2 prismatic joints and 1 revolute joint before the iiwa_link_1 to the given iiwa7 sdf worked! I still do not understand the upper solution did not work, though.